# passing parameters from asp.net to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i want when i click on a row on gridview send it's id to javascript.
for this work i override the rowdatabound event like this:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    GridView1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:test('"e.Row.ClientID"')");
}
```

but it don't working and have errors!
in vb i used from `&` to solving this problem like this:

```
   GridView1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:test('" & e.Row.ClientID & "')");
```

what can i do in `c#`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you should use + for string concatenation, so try this:

```
GridView1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:test('" + e.Row.ClientID + "')");
```

Comment: `javascript:` is not needed in events. Also i don't know what `Row.ClientID` contains but if it has a `'` inside the script will break.